# Sql Server Reporting Services Missing in SharePoint Central admin

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, administration, central-administration, farm-admin

-I had configured the reporting services for my sharepoint farm and
   also I see all the features are added to existing sql server

-But I still see missing my Sql reporting service in SharePoint Central admin under "General Settings" and in "Service application".

-Can any one help me in knowing what what reasons I am missing my features and how can I solve this

[image]

Comment: Did you walk through the installation process at all? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219068(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Yes, I had done but. I found no luck

Comment: You may want to re-read the instructions. SSRS must be installed on the SharePoint server, not SQL Database Engine server. You'll then further want to read the required SSRS Addin configuration and finally, how to install and configure the Service Instance and Service Application.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of SQL installed for your SharePoint 2013. Minimum is Install SQL Server 2012 SP1 is required  so that you will get the features as highlighted in the image below.

[image]

You can find the below link for your reference on SQL Server Version and Installation and why do you need SQL Server 2012 SP1 also mentioned

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/biblog/2012/12/04/installing-and-configuring-sql-reporting-services-on-sharepoint-2013/